# Is it possible to add sockets to items?

Tags: torchlight-2

One rather frequent outcome of item enchanting in Torchlight 1 used to be, especially in the late game, adding sockets to items.

My previous weapon, the Extension Sword (highlights: 452-838 dps physical + 285-556 dps between fire and poison, -9% fumble chance, +20% fire damage, 2 meh enchantments) had a socket that was very well spent with my Eye of Gallo (93 health stolen on hit; hit multiple enemies, gain 93 health multiple times!)

The weapon sadly got superseded by my Beast Hammer of Clouded Vision (562-1055 physical, 90% interrupt chance, 10% blinding cloud), which unfortunately has no sockets.

Can I fix this somehow? I really started to rely on the combined effects of Forcefield (damage absorption) and health steal as a cheap and safe way to heal myself, but the days seem over now. I can still go back to the previous gun, except the general poison theme of Act 3 means giving up half of the elemental damage on that Extension Sword and... yeah, I'd just be happier with rescuing the gem and cramming it on the Hammer somehow. Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are three ways to add sockets:

1. The [Transmuter](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Transmuting_(T2)) will take `one unsocketed item` + `2 gems of equal or greater level` (to the unsocketed item) to consume the gems and place a socket on the item (even magic or enchanted items).
2. There is a small chance for an enchanter to add a socket to an item when asked to enchant it. This will use up one of the limited number of enchants for the item.
3. There is also a wandering enchanter, [Jurick the Socketer](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Enchanting_(T2)), who is guaranteed to add sockets when asked to enchant an item, up to a maximum of two sockets.

The location of Jurick is random. Jurick can spawn at any of the following locations:

- [Plunder Cove](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Plunder_Cove)
- [Icedeep Caverns](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Icedeep_Caverns) - Floor 1
- [Forsaken Vaults](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Forsaken_Vaults)
- [Undercurrents](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Undercurrents)
- [Rivenskull Gorge](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Rivenskull_Gorge)
- [Elemental Oasis](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_Oasis) - Floor 1
- [Fungal Caves](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Fungal_Caves) - Floor 1
- [Rotting Crypt](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Rotting_Crypt) - Floor 1
- [Middenmine](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Middenmine)
- [Vyrax's Tower](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Vyrax%27s_Tower) - Floor 3
- [Exotic Dungeons](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Exotic_Dungeons) (L48-55)
- [Shadowy Grotto](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 2
- [Frostbitten Chasm](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 1
- [Shadowy Caves](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 2
- [Abyssal Grotto](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps)
- [Frostshorn Caverns](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 1
- [Frostshorn Ravine](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 2
- [Frostshorn Chasm](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps) - Floor 1 & 2
- [Shadowy Pit](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Mapworks#Maps)

Comment: The sockets are empty after the process and the gems lost, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Worth noting that Enchanters can also rarely add sockets as an enchanting outcome, and the enchanter Jurik the Socketer is guaranteed to add sockets as his enchanting outcome, up to a maximum of two.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh - Thanks, added that in. Also, a confession. While adding that in, I looked down and realized I had used the exact same wording as you, so I changed it. I glanced again a moment later and discovered that apparently I had been mistaken, as *now* I had the exact same wording. When it happened a third time I got suspicious, and realized I had been looking at the preview instead of your comment. Face, meet Palm.

Comment: It's early, I'll forgive it. :P

Comment: @SaintWacko: Additional note: you only need *one* gem of equal or greater level to the item. The other can be a trash gem and it works just fine. I don't know if this is a bug, but it can really save you gems, and give you a use for outdated gems you're just carrying around.

Answer (score 3):

It is very possible. One of the possible outcomes from visiting an enchanter is that you have a small chance of adding an additional socket, up to a maximum of four.

The cost will increase for each attempt, so make sure you have a fair bit of money, as you're just as likely to either add an additional enchantment, or get nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

There's an NPC that gives sockets. He's really rare. I found him in elemental oasis floor 1.

Answer (score 0):

Tip on getting the enchantments you really want. (IMPORTANT)Save your game before starting and again when you get one that you want. If the enchantment you get isn't one that you want or isn't powerful enough follow this procedure closely. While still in the enchantment screen you can use command-Q to quit. Reload as many times as necessary to get the enchantments that you are hoping for. Rinse and repeat as necessary